# Text width on imageview widget

Tags: android, text, textview, widget, imageview

I have a problem regarding Textview on my battery widget.
The has a picture and on it textview showing the % the problem is that there seems to be something wrong with my code regarding the text width because it allows only 2 characters per verse so it shows for ex. 50 in the first verse and % in the second. How do i set it right? Also side question: can i somehow make the text to always be on the bottom and center? I can do it with padding but it shows differently on each screen size. So anyway here's the code regarding text **EDIT: Here is entire xml file-**:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1_widget"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bateria50_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1_widget"
   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1_widget"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your xml file?

Comment: @kristywelsh Added the entire xml file to the post. Also i've added suggested codes from the bottom comment and altough text show in the bottom and in one line it doesn't get centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For LinearLayout:

`android:singleLine="true"` and `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`

For RelativeLayout:

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Comment: Thanks for replying @Justin Powell. `android:singleLine="true"` worked but `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"` only the bottom part of this worked text is in the bottom left now, could you help?

Comment: @Osama Try putting android:gravity="center_horizontal" on the parent view of your TextView.

Comment: It didn't work, the text is till on the bottom left here is the part of the code maybe i inserted it wrongly? i tried at the beginning of the xml file but it didn't matter either here is the postion part of the code i got now:`<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1_widget"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1_widget"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`

Comment: @Osama Since it is a RelativeLayout, you can use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`. I thought you were using a LinearLayout.